# How big should my hashmap be?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

I do not know in advance how many elements are going to be stored in my `Hashmap` . So how big should the **capacity** of my `HashMap` be ? What factors should I take into consideration here ? I want to minimize the rehashing process as much as possible since it is really expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to have a good tradeoff between space requirement and speed (which is reduced if many collisions happen, which becomes more likely if you reduce the space allocation).

You can define a load factor, the default is probably fine.

But what you also want to avoid is having to rebuild and extend the hash table as it grows. So you want to size it with the maximum capacity up front. Unfortunately, for that, you need to know roughly how much you are going to put into it.

If you can afford to waste a little memory, and at least have a reasonable upper bound for how large it can get, you can use that as the initial capacity. It will never rehash if you stay below that capacity. The memory requirement is linear to the capacity (maybe someone has numbers). **Keep in mind that with a default load factor of 0.75, you need to set your capacity a bit higher than the number of elements, as it will extend the table when it is already 75% full**.

If you really have no idea, just use the defaults. Not because they are perfect in your case, but because you don't have any basis for alternative settings.

The good news is that even if you set suboptimal values, it will still work fine, just waste a bit of memory and/or CPU cycles.

Comment: what does loadfactor =1 mean ?

Comment: @Geek It means the map won't be resized until it is full. If loadfactor = 0.75 (default) the map will be resized when it is 75% full.

Comment: loadFactor=1 means that if you have capacity X, it will put X elements into your hashmap, before resizing. This is crowded, there will be collisions. The default is 0.75, I believe.

Comment: load factor is the maximum ratio between the size and the capacity of a container. Which means when you reach the load factor you need to increase the capacity. `1` is the maximum possible and means you increase capacity only when you cannot add any more objects.

Comment: "full" is relative. You could have loadFactor=2 I imagine... (every bucket is an open-ended list)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) gives the minimum necessary information you need to be able to make a reasonable decision. Read the introduction. I don't know factors you should take into consideration because you have not given details about the nature of your application, the expected load,... My best advice at this stage, let it stay at the default of 16, then do a load testing ( think about the app on the user point of view ) and you'll be able to figure out just roughly how much capacity you need initially.